# Make polyline in google maps not drawable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a polygon drawn on map and it has to be a specific area where ONLY THERE can be drawn a polyline (some sort of geofencing)? Is it possible to do so?

I though of editable and clickable, but its not exactly what i want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out the solution.

There is the code (in case someone will need it)

```
function addLatLng(event) {

  var path = poly.getPath();

if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, bermudaTriangle)){
  path.push(event.latLng);
  console.log(path);
}

}
```